# JOINs with compound ON clause in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I thought MS-Access supported compound ON clauses, but I keep getting "Run-time error '3296': JOIN expression not supported.  Here is a simplified version of my FROM clause:

```
(A  INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.idA) LEFT JOIN C ON ((C.idA = A.ID) AND (C.idB = B.ID))
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parentheses around the multiple join criteria are messing it up. It should be

```
(A  INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.idA) LEFT JOIN C ON (C.idA = A.ID) AND (C.idB = B.ID)
```

This is just my intuition, because in order to do an efficient join Access has to examine all the table indexes that are involved in the join criteria, so logically the `AND` belongs to the `ON` expression.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that didn't make any difference.  I got the same error.